# New member not able to see all other existing members in the audio room

Tags: react-native, agora.io

We are building an audio broadcasting app.  The issue is that when the audio room has more than 3 users, now when another user joins the room, he/she sometimes can only see a portion of the existing users in the room. (This issue does not happen all the time)

The way we are implementing this is that when a user joins the room, existing members use the method sendMessageToPeer to send the info of themselves to the new user. My guess is that some sendMessageToPeer calls may fail and that causes some members not showing up in the new users' screen.

My questions are:

1. are we doing it correctly? If not, what should be the right way?
2. Is there a way to fetch a batch of the existing users in the room?
3. If this is the right we to send info the new users, would it be very slow if there are many users in the audio room

```
this._rtmEngine.on('channelMemberJoined', evt => {
      const {rtcUid} = this.state
      const {userData} = this.props

      // send data to new joined user
      this._rtmEngine?.sendMessageToPeer({
        peerId: evt.uid,
        text:
          this.state.rtcUid +
          ':' +
          userData._id +
          ':' +
          userData.profilePicUrl +
          ':' +
          userData.firstName,
        offline: false,
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you also getting the new users information to the existing users in the channel?
You can do this by sending a channel message to all the existing users in the channel when someone joins an audio room.
If you've covered that then the code snippet looks correct, I'd check if the message is failing by adding `console.log`(s) on the recipient end.

You can get members in an RTM channel using [`getMembers`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmchannel.html#getmembers) method.